# A logic question about Karl's favorite brownie recipe

Tags: logic, puzzle

I have been trying to solve the following problem:

Karl’s favorite brownie recipe uses semisweet chocolate, very little
flour, and less than 1/4 cup sugar. He has four recipes: one **French**, one **Swiss**,
one **German**, and one **American**. *Each of the four has at least two of the qualities*
Karl wants in a brownie recipe. ***Exactly three** use very little flour, **exactly three** use
semisweet chocolate, and **exactly three** use less than 1/4 cup sugar.
The **Swiss** and the **German** recipes use different kinds of chocolate. The **American**
and the **German** recipes use the same amount of flour, but different kinds of
chocolate. The **French** and the **American** recipes use the same amount of flour. The
**German** and **American** recipes do not both use less than 1/4 cup sugar.*
Karl is very excited because one of these is his favorite recipe. Which one is it?

The following is my attempted solution:

From three of the statements given in the problem: "*The **Swiss** and the **German** recipes use different kinds of chocolate.*", "*The **American**
and the **German** recipes use the same amount of flour, but different kinds of chocolate.*", and "***Exactly three**  recipes use semisweet chocolate.*",
one can deduce that the **German** recipe does not use the semisweet chocolate because the **German** recipe uses different kind of chocolate from both
the **Swiss** and the **American** recipes. Because each of the four recipes has at least two of the qualities Karl wants in a brownie recipe, it follows that the **German**  recipe use
both very little flour and less than 1/4 cup sugar.

From three of the statements given in the problem: "*The **American** and the **German** recipes use the same amount of flour, but different kinds of chocolate.*", "*The **French** and the **American** recipes use the same amount of flour.*", and  "***Exactly three** recipes use  very little flour.*", one can deduce that the **Swiss** recipe does not use very little flour.

Because both the **German** and the **Swiss** recipe have only two of the qualities Karl wants for a brownie recipe, they both are not Karl's favorite recipe.

The statement "*The **German** and **American** recipes do not both use less than 1/4 cup sugar.*" means the **German** recipe or the **American** recipe and not both uses less than 1/4 cup sugar.
Because the **German** recipe uses both very little flour and less than 1/4 cup sugar, the **American** recipe does not use less than 1/4 cup sugar. It follows that the **American** recipe is not Karl's favorite.

Therefore, Karl's favorite recipe is the ***French recipe***.

My questions are whether the statement "*The **German** and **American** recipes do not both use less than 1/4 cup sugar.*" means *the **German** recipe or the **American** recipe and not both uses less than 1/4 cup sugar* and whether the statement "The **German** and **American** recipes do not both use less than 1/4 cup sugar." is equivalent to the statement "Both the **German** and the **American** recipes do not use less than 1/4 cup sugar." or not?

The question is from the book: Daepp, U., & Gorkin, P. (2011). Reading, writing, and proving: A closer look at mathematics. In *Reading, writing, and proving: A closer look at mathematics* (2nd ed., p. 31). New York: Springer.

Comment: It means that at least one of the them uses at least $1/4$ cup of sugar.  It possible that they both do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On its own,

> *"The German and American recipes do not both use less than 1/4 cup sugar."*

means that one or two of them use too much sugar.

But you are also told *"exactly three use less than 1/4 cup sugar"* so in this question only one can use too much sugar.

Comment: Is the statement "The German and American recipes do not both use less than 1/4 cup sugar." equivalent to "Both the German and the American recipes do not use less than 1/4 cup sugar."?

Comment: @Approxiz You are getting into English language, but I would read your last example as saying the two of them each use too much sugar.

Comment: But if that is the case, is not the given statement "The German and American recipes do not both use less than 1/4 cup sugar." contradicts with the given statement "Exactly three recipes use less than 1/4 cup sugar."? Because if the statement "The German and American recipes do not both use less than 1/4 cup sugar." means two of them each uses too much sugar, then only two recipes use less than 1/4 cup of sugar.

Comment: @Approxiz No - because "they do not both do something" is not the same as "they both do not do something".  In English, changing the word order can change meanings.

Comment: So, is the statement "A and B do not both use C." means exactly 1 of the them uses C, A or B uses C (can be both), or means both A and B do not use C? Sorry for asking many questions. I am confuse.

Comment: "A and B do not both use C" means the same as "it is false that A and B both use C".  One of A and B might not use C, or two of A and B might not use C.